PhpStorm - Parameter Type hints not appearing
Currently I've all Inlay Hints enabled in my PhpStorm settings:

But there are no type hints appearing beside the parameters on functions. I'm only seeing the Usages and Author as a hint above the function itself.
Not sure what setting I'm missing to re-enable this.


Please show the screenshot of the actual editor. It may depend on a context (so need to see more). Ideally to have a single file that can be copy pasted to test it locally. So far I see nothing wrong here (but I might be missing the point) 2) And in case you are talking about different thing (may happen with anybody, confused with some another feature) -- do you have a reference screenshot of the feature in question? 3) Does this happens with ALL functions/calls or only some of them?


Am I confused?  The method declaration is where you "set" the data types of the parameters.  Where you call the method is where you might see the ghost text indicating the expected type of the passed in data.  Right?

@chdonncha Did you manage to resolve your issue? If not: please provide screenshots/mock ups of 1) what you have right now and 2) what you want to see (hint: go over PhpStorm Help pages on that subject -- it should have the screenshot of the feature in action)
